# Pivot SQL Server results by year

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I am at a loss on how to return pivoted results.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  My data look like this:

[image]

Notice SystemCategoryID and DataQualityCategoryID 3 has a record for 2019 and another for 2020.  I need to pivot result like this:

[image]

Because SystemCategoryID and DataQualityCategoryID 3 has a record for 2020 it would be returned in the same row as the previous year.  So if there is data for multiple years only return current year and previous year.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please don't use images for data/T-SQL, use formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation like this:

```
select clientid, systemcategoryid, dataqualitycategoryid,
    max(case when year(datecaptured) = 2019 then datecaptured end) as datecaptured_2019,
    max(case when year(datecaptured) = 2019 then score        end) as score_2019
    max(case when year(datecaptured) = 2020 then datecaptured end) as datecaptured_2020,
    max(case when year(datecaptured) = 2019 then score        end) as score_2020
from mytable
where datecaptured >= '20190101' and datecaptured < '20210101'
group by month(datecaptured), day(datecaptured), clientid, systemcategoryid, dataqualitycategoryid
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a `left join` to me:

```
select t2019.*, t2020.datecaptured, t2020.score
from t t2019 left join
     t t2020
     on t2020.clientid = t2019.clientid and
        t2020.systemcategoryid = t2019.systemcategoryid and
        t2020.dataqualitycategoryid = t2019.dataqualitycategoryid and
        t2020.datecaptured = dateadd(year, 1, t2019.datecaptured)
where t2019.datecaptured >= '2019-01-01' and
      t2019.datecaptured < '2020-01-01'
```